# Code generation using loop

Tags: c#

I am new to `C#` programming. I have number of text boxes on a form and instead of writing the same code for each text box, is it possible to use loop for writing same code for each text box? In the code below can we use the variable `i` for the same?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(amountTextBox.Text);
        MessageBox.Show(amountTextBox1.Text);
        MessageBox.Show(amountTextBox2.Text);
        MessageBox.Show(amountTextBox3.Text);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to generate code (which is *a lot* harder than it sounds), whenever you have variables named `something1`, `something2`, … `somethingN`, you should consider using an array, or some other collection.

Create an array of text boxes, like this:

```
var amountTextBoxes = new[] { amountTextBox, amountTextBox1, amountTextBox2, amountTextBox3 };
```

And then loop through them like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < amountTextBoxes.Length; i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(amountTextBoxes[i].Text);
}
```

Or like this:

```
foreach (var textBox in amountTextBoxes)
{
    MessageBox.Show(textBox.Text);
}
```

Another option that would probably work in this specific case, (though this solution is not as general as the previous one) involves directly searching for the controls based on the name. If this is a Windows Forms application, you could use [`Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (assuming all controls have the same name pattern):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    var controlName = "amountTextBoxes" + i;
    vat textBox = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find(controlName, true)[0];
    MessageBox.Show(textBox.Text);
}
```

Or if this is WPF, you could use [`FindName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    var controlName = "amountTextBoxes" + i;
    vat textBox = (TextBox)this.FindName(controlName);
    MessageBox.Show(textBox.Text);
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution for any number of textboxes that one could realistically expect to appear on a form. And for unrealistic numbers, you could do something like `foreach (var textBox in Controls.OfType<TextBox>().OrderBy(t => t.Name)) { ... }`

Comment: @ta.speot.is only if you want to do the same thing for *all* the textboxes in `Controls`.

Comment: Filter them by name, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
{
  if (x is TextBox)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(((TextBox)x).Text);
   }
}
```

Comment: Now they can appear in any order. And what do you have against `Enumerable.OfType` ?

Answer (score 2):

Better version with [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method:

```
foreach (TextBox x in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().OrderBy(x => x.Name))
{
     MessageBox.Show(x.Text);
}
```

Comment: A tester has just filed a bug report: the fourth amount is shown before the first. Troubleshoot why.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Then we can use `OrderBy` ?

Comment: That will do a lexical sort by `Name`. I believe `TextBox100` will appear before `TextBox1`

Comment: yes, if he has 100 textBoxes in the same form! to fix this he/she can write his/her own comparer.I need some sleep :D

Comment: It follows that `TextBox10` will appear before `TextBox1`, too. Is 10 text box controls too many?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a linq version.

```
this.Controls
   .OfType<TextBox>()
   .ToList()
   .ForEach(control => 
     MessageBox.Show(control.Text));
```

Comment: What if `amountTextBox3.Name` is `a` and `amountTextBox.Name` is `z`? Now the fourth amount appears before the first.

Comment: What if `amountTextBox3` is in the `Controls` collection before `amountTextBox`? Now the fourth amount appears before the first.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using for loop you can do like this also..
***note *** - This is for all the textbox controls in the form.. for specific textboxes you may use a for loop which loop through an array or collection of text boxes you need .

```
foreach(Control control in this.Controls)

{

if(control.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))

{
MessageBox.Show(control.Text);


}

}
```

Comment: *This is for all the textbox controls in the form* And without regard for order, either.

Answer (score 0):

As Selman22 mentioned you can solved it using this.Controls.OfType(). You can further refine your query as mentioned below

```
foreach (TextBox textBox in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(x => x.Name.Contains("amountTextBox")).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList())
        {
            MessageBox.Show(textBox.Text);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple and maintainable way would be to `yield return` every textbox you're interested in, in the order that you're interested in, and then iterate over that.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var textBox in GetAmountTextBoxes())
        MessageBox.Show(textBox.Text);
}

private IEnumerable<TextBox> GetAmountTextBoxes()
{
    yield return amountTextBox;
    yield return amountTextBox1;
    yield return amountTextBox2;
    yield return amountTextBox3;
}
```

If you have many textboxes and maintaining this list is cumbersome, you could generalise it to something like:

```
return Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
```

But take care to filter it, if necessary, to only the textbox controls you need with `Where`.

And if order is important, you'll need to devise some function to sort the textboxes (in conjunction with `OrderBy`). This is necessary because the default sorting algorithm will sort `TextBox10` before `TextBox1`.

Answer (score -5):

Your Code Rewritten:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(amountTextBox[i].Text);
    }
```

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {MessageBox.Show(amountTextBox[i].Text);
    }
}

Comment: what i posted was the correct body inside the loop! Now the question is corrected too!

Comment: Where did `amountTextBox` come from? In the question it's clearly a `TextBox`. It doesn't have an indexer.